# How To Split Two Intersecting Circles in to Three Separate Shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

My question is specifically about **Making a Venn Diagram in Adobe Illustrator**.

I am trying to make a Venn-diagram to visualize different set operations in math. I found that Illustrator made some pretty good pictures but I am stuck now.

I  want to turn the part of the `Circle A` that does not intersect with the `Circle B` into its own object so that I can fill it with a color.

The problem is that the intersection of A and B is one object, and the complement of the intersection is also one object.

So if I try to fill `Circle A`, but **not** the intersection with a color, it also fills `Circle B` minus the intersection.

In other words, currently the two circle make up two object, but I want to turn it in to three separate objects that share sides. I used the pathfinder tool to get this far, but I don't know how to use it to get what I want.

How can I create three separate shapes from the shape in the diagram below, one for `Circle A` without the intersecting part of the circle, the same for `Circle B` and one more shape for the intersecting part?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select both circles and click the **Divide** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**. This will create 3 separate shapes.

[image: divide]

[image: shapes]

You can also simply grab the **Live Paint Bucket Tool** and click once on the circles to create a Live Paint Group, then continue clicking areas to fill them with color. When done click the **Expand** button on the control bar across the top of the screen to expand the Live Paint Group to 3 standard shapes.